# Convert Place Name & Address to Google Maps URL And iFrame

Tags: google-maps

### Background

I'm working in WordPress and want to display embedded Google Maps `iframes`. I have added a custom metabox in the backend to hold a text string.

### Currently

I create the map link using Google Maps, and then save the entire embeddable iframe code. This adds another step to the work flow. I have to manually go to Google Maps, find the address, and save the `iframe` code.

## Goal

I'd prefer to just save the address and have my `PHP` convert it to an `iframe`. Is there a way in the Google Maps API to get an `iframe` just by sending the address and possibly the place name?

Comment: What do you mean you can't put the address directly into the url?

Comment: I can if I want to make it a clickable link.
[link](https://www.google.com/maps/preview?q=145+E+3rd+St+Marion,+IN+46952).  
I can't though for the iframe code.

Comment: I don't see why not : http://jsfiddle.net/8rvwt/

Comment: Your fiddle is using the old Google Maps.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Updated As of Jan. 2016

Google allows for a URL call that uses an address directly and works in an iframe. You just need to tell Google (as **[coding addicted pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34861389/2111901)**) in the call that the output is embedded.

You make a call to:

```
https://www.google.com/maps
```

And you give two GET parameters:

```
q=[ADDRESS]
output=embed
```

The iframe call would look like this in HTML:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps?q=[ADDRESS]&output=embed"></iframe>
```

Example:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps?q=Randall Miller %26 Associates 300 E Broadway, Logansport, IN 46947&output=embed"></iframe>
```

So using PHP, which was part of my original question, I'd put:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps?q=<?php echo $name . ' ' . $address; ?>&output=embed"></iframe>
```

This is working as of July, 14, 2016.

Comment: I know I'm late to the game, but thought I'd share anyway for others. The ampersand (&) isn't escaped, so when you load up that url you're actually telling the website to ignore everything after the ampersand or that it should try to evaluate the stuff after the ampersand as something else. If you replace the "&" with "%26" (without quotes), you'll fix the initial problem.

Comment: I'm glad Google has fixed that, also nice find with the "near" tag. Thanks for attributing me in your answer.

Comment: The near tag doesn't seem to be a good solution (maybe something's changed?). The `near` example you give pulls up the Randall Miller & Associates at 145 E 3rd St, Marion, IN 46952

Comment: AndyM, your answer doesn't seems to work anymore. If I copy and past your iframe, it's not working, nothing shows up. Any updates on your solution?

Comment: This one is working:  `src='https://maps.google.com/maps?&q="your_address_formated_as_you_want"&output=embed'` Maybe just update your answer if you're fine with it or I can put an answer.

Comment: you can also use lat long instead of address `q=48.8584,2.2945`

Answer (score 27):

Maybe  it's little bit late but just in case any one needed it

to get the location in the new api formation follow these steps

- Visit: https://www.google.com/maps/ and search for the area you want
  to display on your site.
- Once the area is shown on the map,open side drawer if it exists or  click the gear (cog) icon on the bottom right of the screen if it exists.
- Click the "Share" button.
- Click the "Embed map" tap.
- Choose your options and copy the iframe code given to you on that screen.

Sample:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d852.8754667521503!2d29.96481543232134!3d31.23452741247449!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0000000000000000%3A0x2eb3093918d73855!2sHeba!5e0!3m2!1sen!2seg!4v1446570384113" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mohammad. Thanks for the late answer. However, your answer doesn't work. The address isn't in the final `iframe`. The goal here is to convert an address into an `iframe`.

Comment: Hi Andy In case you didn't solve it already please post the address you want to convert and I'll try with it. Do you want to display google maps `iframe` in your site pointing to that address or what?  :)

Comment: It's already solved ... see the above answer. The final URL is what goes into the `iframe` `scr` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

The solutions wasn't working for me (jan 2016). Here is what I used in my iframe to get it:

```
src='https://maps.google.com/maps?&q=your_address_formated_as_you_want&output‌​=embed'
```

Complete iframe code:

```
<iframe src='https://maps.google.com/maps?&q=your_address_formated_as_you_want&output‌​=embed'></iframe>
```

Comment: I've updated the answer with the new information about `output`, thank you! Please note, I tested and found that the double quotations are not needed.

Comment: Great! I think that I put the double quotations as a 'reflex' to mark that the sentence was to changed in your code. I'll remove them for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

In your answer, you said you fixed it but you had to reverse them. The problem was actually due to not escaping the special characters in the URL. Ampersand (&) is a special character in the address bar that tells the server you are passing it a variable, so essentially everything after the ampersand is being ignored.

The fix is simple, change **&** with **%26**.

E.g.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Randall Miller %26 Associates, 300 E Broadway, Logansport, IN 46947
```

Personally I would escape everything else too, such as the spaces with **%20** and the commas with **%2C**.

E.g.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=Randall%20Miller%20%26%20Associates%2C%20300%20E%20Broadway%2C%20Logansport%2C%20IN%2046947
```

For a list of escape codes, please [visit this page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

I know the escape codes makes it harder to read, but it prevents any faults/errors/bugs from happening.

Comment: That's so weird that it does that. Is it possible that Google has released different versions for different locales? (I'm in the UK). Here is what I see when I type in that second URL into a browser: https://www.dropbox.com/s/djp4v8cwvxxeprr/Screenshot%202014-04-03%2015.38.55.png - I know the url is different to what I pasted in, but google redirected it to that automatically. Also, thanks for the +1 :).

Comment: Seems to work here too, nice find! I guess it could be any combination of the above, only Google will really know. Glad you find a solution though.